# Wscript 'document' not defined

Tags: javascript

Hi i just discovered Wscript and i tried to run a script that is meant to run on a browser and i got the above error, i understand what the problem is, but i wanted to ask if there is a way to define the document object(html file and cookies) maybe from command prompt or maybe from the javascript file itself.

```
var _cuesToken='g9QI2Els_LJHH3rTTFoE_vCvQAo:1333015760479';
var _userToken='4454682648';
var document='out.html';
var cues_meta1 = document.createElement('meta');     cues_meta1.name='com.google.ads.apps.servers.cues.CuesRelease::gwt:property';     cues_meta1.content='baseUrl=/cues/';
var cues_meta2 = document.createElement('meta');     cues_meta2.name='com.google.ads.apps.servers.cues.Cues::gwt:property';     cues_meta2.content='baseUrl=/cues/';
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(cues_meta1);
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(cues_meta2);
window._cuesMS='n';
```

.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
var ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.Navigate("about:blank");
var dom = ie.Document;
ie.Quit();
WScript.Echo(typeof dom);
```

From: http://www.webmasters.am/blog/wsh-jscript-access-dom/javascript/2010/04/ (dead link)